# CSS Select for selectpicker via class ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have two classes: selectpicker with different IDs: *selected_Test_Platforms* and *selected_SIL_relevant*
I want to set *selected_Test_Platforms* to a preselection that comes from an array -> *availableTestPlatforms*

It only works with the selector **$('.selectpicker')** but that obviously selects both and that is not my intention.

**So how do I select and set only id="selected_Test_Platforms" to the array availableTestPlatforms.**

```js
   //works but selects both IDs 
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', availableTestPlatforms);
    
//does not work
$( "#selected_SIL_relevant" ).selectpicker('val', availableTestPlatforms);
$('select[name=selValue]').selectpicker('val', availableTestPlatforms);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Report manipulation options:</a>
      </div>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="selValue" id="selected_Test_Platforms" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="selected_SIL_relevant" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-actions-box="true">
              <option value='-All-' selected>-All-</option>
              <option value='Safety Relevant'>Safety Relevant</option>
              <option value='QM'>QM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="main()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: If `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker(` works then `$("#selected_Test_Platforms").selectpicker` should also work.   I'm not sure why you've tried only `$("#selected_SIL_relevant..` and stated it doesn't work when that's not your requirement.

Comment: Thank you I simple took the wrong ID name by taking $("#selected_Test_Platforms") it works now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `$('#selected_Test_Platforms')` for id

Comment: ok thanks for the hint, I simply took the wrong id name. $( "#selected_Test_Platforms" ).selectpicker('val', availableTestPlatforms); is working now.

Comment: cool, happy to help